# pass reversed url to knockout.js model

Tags: javascript, python, django, url, knockout.js

I got **django template** with **knockout.js** bindings, with list which is should be filled as one press  button:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
   <li data-bind="text: title"><li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: fillList">Show</button>
```

and some knockout model:

```
function ItemsModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();

    self.fillList = function() {
        // some download data logic
        ...
    }
}
```

Functon **fillList** gets data from server. It should send request to url. I use reversed url:

```
{% url "app.views.get_items" %}
```

What is the best way to pass that **template-generated url** to **ItemsModel**, so it knows where it should get the data?

Pass it as parameter to model?

```
function ItemsModel(url_get_items) {
     ...
}
```

Maybe pass it as parameter with click event?

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { fillList('{% url "app.views.get_items" %}') }">
```

Or use submit binding instead?

```
<form action="{% url "app.views.get_items" %}" data-bind="submit: fillList">
    <button type="submit">Show</button>
</form>
```

Something else? Is there any best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put the url in a attribute on an element which I read in the script and pass to the view model when it's created. Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app" data-url="your/url/here">
    <span data-bind="text: url"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {
    function ItemsModel(url) {
    var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();

        // Adding an observable just to prove its accessible here.
        self.url = ko.observable(url);

        self.fillList = function () {
            // some download data logic from url
        }
    }

    var url = document.getElementById('app').getAttribute('data-url');
    console.log(url);
    ko.applyBindings( new ItemsModel(url) ,document.getElementById('app')) ;
}());
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nLvk2zp/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. That got some sense, but what you do if you have several urls?

Comment: I usually add a base url if there are more urls. Or perhaps several base urls.

Answer (score 0):

So, answering my own questing. The best way I've found, and successfully used is to pass to model urls object. Commonly it looks like this:

```
<script>
    var model = new ItemsModel({
        csrf: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        url: {
            'items': '{% url "items.views.items.api.list" %}',
            ...
            'remove_item': '{% url "items.views.items.api.remove" %}'
        }
    });
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

Using AMD style is a bit cleaner. You can create module in html page like this:

```
<script>
    define('settings', { 
        csrf: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        url: {
            'items': '{% url "items.views.items.api.list" %}',
            ...
            'remove_item': '{% url "items.views.items.api.remove" %}'
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then refer to it in required script:

```
require(['settings', 'knockout'], function (settings, ko) {
    var model = new ItemsModel(settings);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

If you plan to use r.js you should provide empty path for settings in config, like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: 'items-app',
    out: 'dist/items.js',
    paths: {
        'knockout': 'path/to/knockout',
        'settings': 'empty:',
    }
})
```

The only problem is that this method doesn't work with urls with params. The easiest workaround is to pass all parameters either with post or with get method.